# How to change the Datatable heading name of CRUD Admin Generator

Tags: php, mysql, crud, crud-admin-generator

I am using CRUD Admin Generator and I have successfully created initially my crud for my tables. When I browse on the codes. I find difficult in changing the heading title of my Datatable column name. Is there anyone out there tried this CRUD Admin Generator? I am reffering to this framework -> http://crud-admin-generator.com

Answer (score 0):

;) no one answers to my question. I just got it manually by changing the default array found in the view files.